# Linux Virtual to Physical Mapping to RAM

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a simple question regarding Linux.

Let us Suppose we have 1GB RAM. I read that Out of this 1GB RAM

1GB RAM is itself divided into High Mem and Low mem
High Mem is 128MB and Low Mem is 896MB (Both are 1GB total)

My Question is Where is the 0x0GB to 3GB data mapped into RAM

1) user space is 3GB - Where does it reside in the RAM? If the 896 MB + High is
   already occupying the entire RAM. Where is the space for the Userspace 3GB RAM?

```
4GB     +---------------+-------------+
        |     128MB     |             | 
        +---------------+ <------+    |->|------------+                 
        |     896MB     |        |       |   128MB    | 
    3GB +---------------+ <--+   +------>+------------+ 
        |               |    |           | 896 MB     |
        |     /////     |    +---------->+------------+
        |               |     
    0GB +---------------+
```

Comment: Then what about 128MB reserved seperately (Vmalloc region) - Is this only available for kernel calls (vmalloc) only. Or A part of this is also used for user processes?

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing different concepts. The [0-3GB] + [3-4GB] areas are in virtual address space (and that particular layout is very specific to i386 [i.e. x86 32-bit], btw).

If you have 1GB of RAM, the available physical memory is mapped via the virtual address space. It is possible (and in many cases, likely) for the same physical page of memory to be mapped more than once.

By default, in i386, the low 896MB of RAM is direct-mapped into kernel virtual address space starting at the 3GB mark (0xc0000000). The lowest several megabytes is actually used by the kernel for its code and data areas. Most of the rest is then placed into allocation pools where it can subsequently be allocated for use by the kernel or by user processes.

So, user virtual address space uses some of the same physical memory. Physical pages are allocated one-by-one as needed by a process and mapped into the low 3GB of virtual space. This mapping changes every time there is a context switch. That is, process A's virtual address space maps different sets of pages than process B's -- except that the kernel part (above 0xc0000000) will not change.

When actually executing code, every code or data address used in the program is a virtual address. The virtual address gets translated to a physical address in hardware by page tables. The kernel sets up and completely controls the page tables.

Comment: Gil Hamilton: Not sure if you recieved my comment: here it is again: 
Then what about 128MB reserved seperately (Vmalloc region) - Is this only available for kernel calls (vmalloc) only. Or A part of this is also used for user processes?

Comment: The 128MB is virtual space. It's not actually setting aside 128MB of RAM. This 128MB region can be used to map in individual pages (otherwise the kernel would not be able to get to anything not already direct-mapped). In other words, it's space available for temporary mappings. And yes, this area is only available to the kernel. User-space is never allowed to access anything above virtual address 0xc0000000.

Comment: I did not understand this - "otherwise the kernel would not be able to get to anything not already direct-mapped". Can you explain please. I get confused. Also What do you mean by Temporary mappings?

Comment: Direct-mapped means one-to-one mapping for each page virtual=>physical:  [0xc0000000=>00000000, 0xc0001000=>00001000 ... 0xf7fff000=>37fff000].  Any other RAM (physical address above 0x38000000) is only accessible to the kernel when it is explicitly mapped somewhere in the virtual window starting at 0xf8000000 (top 128MB). This is used when accessing a PCI device's BAR for example, and for any other reason the kernel has to access data outside the low 896MB of RAM. ("Temporary mappings" is really not correct. The memory may be allocated/reserved early in boot and kept until shutdown.)

Comment: @GilHamilton, I wish I could upvote your answer and comments to infinity. Thanks!!